# Как правильно сказать: боюсь собакУ или боюсь собакИ?

Tags: склонение

Как правильно говорить: боюсь собакУ или боюсь собакИ?

Answer (score 1):

**В качестве эпиграфа**: Если вы боитесь **собаку (В.п.)** — вы жертва, а жертву надо если уж не съесть, то продемонстрировать свое превосходство над ней (из Интернета).

**Из словаря**: БОЯТЬСЯ,  нсв. 1. кого-чего. Испытывать боязнь (о человеке или животном). Б. хулиганов, учителя, отца. Б. грозы, землетрясения. Мышей и собак смертельно боюсь.

**В словаре указан Р.п.,** глагол возвратный (с частицей СЯ), что, казалось бы, тут думать? Но нет, этот вопрос встречается очень часто, потому что **на практике используются обе падежные формы.**

Почему? **В общей формулировке это звучит так: В.п. полного объекта конкурирует с Р.п. неполного объекта.**

Глагол возвратный? Ничего страшного, это просто залог возвратный, а глагол описывает ваши чувства по отношению к объекту (вы как бы ментально на него всё-таки воздействуете, и собака это чувствует). Поэтому В.п. используется наряду с Р.п., и приходится учитывать **разные факторы:** конкретность или абстрактность, ограничительный характер действия или нет. **На практике это выглядит так.**

1) Если вы в принципе испытывает дискомфорт при виде собаки, то лучше сказать "я боюсь собак". Тогда  вопрос о падежах уже не обсуждается, так как существительное одушевленное (формы Р.п. и В.п совпадают).

2) Единственное число желательно использовать, когда речь идет **о конкретной собаке** - о той, которую вы видите сейчас или о  существовании которой знаете (конкретность обозначает В.п.).

а) Не могу пройти, потому что боюсь собаку, которая  стоит на дороге (В.п., боюсь именно сейчас и конкретно эту собаку).

б) Не люблю заходить к другу, потому что боюсь его собаки/собаку (Р.п. или В.п.,  вообще боюсь, а не сейчас, но собака тоже конкретная).

**Обсуждение вопроса о собаках:**

- [Как правильно говорить: "боюсь собаки" или "боюсь собаку"? | bolshoyvopros.ru](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2368384-kak-pravilno-govorit-bojus-sobaki-ili-bojus-sobaku.html)
- ["Не бойся собаки" or "не бойся собаку"? | Russian Language Stack Exchange](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-or-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83)

Answer (score 0):

Возвратные глаголы всегда не переходные, то есть правильно "боюсь собаки"